# Syntax error on second def

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax-error, function

When running this code I have trouble with the second def, **de**f multiply (): with the de of def being singed out when i receive the syntax error.

```
import random
def start () :

    print "Welcome!"
    choose ()

def choose () :

    choice = input """would you like to
     add, subtract, or multiply?
      1       2            3
    """
    if choice = 1 :
        add ()
    if choice = 2 :
        subtract ()
    if choice = 3 :
        multiply ()


def multiply () :

    x = random.random ()
    x = round ()
    y = random.random ()
    y = round ()
    print "What is the answer to: ", x,"*", y, " ?"
    answer = input ": "
    z = x*y
    if answer == z :
        print "you are correct!"
    elif answer < z :
        print "your answer is low! The correct answer was ", z
    elif answer > z :
        print "your answer is high! The correct answer was ", z
    multiply ()

def add () :

    x = random.random ()
    x = round ()
    y = random.random ()
    y = round ()
    print "What is the answer to: ", x,"+", y, " ?"
    answer = input ": "
    z = x+y
    if answer == z :
        print "you are correct!"
    elif answer < z :
        print "your answer is low! The correct answer was ", z
    elif answer > z :
        print "your answer is high! The correct answer was ", z

def subtract () :

    x = random.random ()
    x = round ()
    y = random.random ()
    y = round ()
    print "What is the answer to: ", x,"*", y, " ?"
    answer = input ": "
    z = x*y
    if answer == z :
        print "you are correct!"
    elif answer < z :
        print "your answer is low! The correct answer was ", z
    elif answer > z :
        print "your answer is high! The correct answer was ", z
```

Answer (score 2):

`input` is a function, so you have to call it like one:

```
input('Input some stuff: ')
```

You also have a few lines that look like this:

```
if choice = 1 :
```

You want to write `choice == 1`. Finally, this part right here is a little strange:

```
x = random.random ()
x = round ()
```

You probably want to pass `x` into `round`:

```
x = random.random ()
x = round (x)
```

Or just skip that part entirely and use `randint`

```
x = random.randint(0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some logic and syntax errors in your code:

`answer = input ": "`

You call input like this:

`answer = input(": ")`

---

`if choice = 1 :`

= is assignment. You mean ==.

---

```
x = random.random ()
x = round ()
```

If you assign x to be the first thing, then the second thing, it's like the first assignment never happened. Did you mean `x = round(x)`?

---